# Sub menu accordion closes when it should open (nested accordion logic seems off)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a multi-nested accordion menu is currently behaving glitchy.

When I'm clicking into a submenu (i.e. "*what we deliver 2*", it closes the main accordion and then when I open the main accordion, that's when the sub accordion opens. See this gif for a demo of my issue:

[image]

I'm trying to simply open and close each accordion on it's `li` click, but unsure why it closes the entire parent accordion and then appears once the parent accordion opens (it's the same behaviour when closing the sub accordions, as shown in the `gif`).

**Demo:**

```js
$(function() {

  /*
  * define vars
  */

  const header = $(".header");
  const hamburger_trigger = $(".hamburger__trigger");
  const hamburger_popup = $(".hamburger__popup");

  /*
  * open hamburger on click
  */

  $(hamburger_trigger).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(header).toggleClass("hamburger--open");
    $(hamburger_popup).toggleClass("active");
  });


  /*
  * hamburger submenu
  */

  $(".hamburger--has-submenu").click(function() {

    console.log("click");

    var child_menu = $(this).children(".hamburger__submenu");

    if ($(this).hasClass("hamburger__submenu--open")) {
      $(this).removeClass("hamburger__submenu--open");
      child_menu.removeClass("d-block");
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("hamburger__submenu--open");
      child_menu.addClass("d-block");

    }

  });


  // for children submenus

  $(".hamburger-trigger-submenu").click(function() {
    console.log("click");

    var child_menu = $(this).children(".hamburger__submenu");

    if ($(this).hasClass("hamburger__submenu--open")) {
      child_menu.removeClass("hamburger__submenu--open");
    } else {
      child_menu.addClass("hamburger__submenu--open");
    }

  });



});
```

```css
/* HEADER */
.header {
  padding: 30px 0;
}

/* HAMBURGER */
.hamburger__trigger {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.hamburger__trigger:hover {
  color: green;
}
.hamburger__popup {
  background: black;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
  height: 0;
  padding: 40px 15px 140px 15px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.hamburger__popup.active {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.3s;
  animation: fadeIn 0.3s;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.hamburger__popup-inner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: auto;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.hamburger__li > a {
  margin: 10px 0;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
.hamburger__submenu--level-2, .hamburger__submenu--level-3, .hamburger__submenu--level-4 {
  display: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

/* GENERAL */
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.background--black {
  background: #000000;
}

.color--white {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<header class="header background--black">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-end">
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="hamburger">
          <span class="hamburger__trigger color--white">Click me</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="hamburger__popup">
    <div class="hamburger__popup-inner color--white">
      <nav class="hamburger__menu w-100">
        <ul class="hamburger__menu-ul">

          <!-- MAIN GROUP -->
          <li class="hamburger__li hamburger__depth-1 hamburger--has-submenu ">
            <a class="hamburger__parent-item color--white" href="#">
              What we deliver
            </a>

            <!-- SUB MENU IN MAIN GROUP -->
            <ul class="hamburger__submenu hamburger__submenu--level-2">

              <li class="hamburger__li hamburger__depth-2 hamburger--has-submenu hamburger-trigger-submenu">
                <a class="hamburger__link color--white hamburger__submenu-trigger" href="#">
                  <span>What we deliver 2</span>
                </a>
                <!-- SUB MENU WITHIN SUBMENU -->
                <ul class="hamburger__submenu hamburger__submenu--level-3">
                  <li class="hamburger__li hamburger__depth-3  hamburger-trigger-submenu">
                    <a class="hamburger__link color--white position-relative" href="#">
                      What we deliver 2.1
                    </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- SUB MENU WITHIN SUBMENU END-->
              </li>

              <li class="hamburger__li hamburger__depth-2 hamburger--has-submenu hamburger-trigger-submenu">
                <a class="hamburger__link color--white hamburger__submenu-trigger" href="#">
                  <span>What we deliver 3</span>
                </a>
                <!-- SUB MENU WITHIN SUBMENU -->
                <ul class="hamburger__submenu hamburger__submenu--level-3">
                  <li class="hamburger__li hamburger__depth-3  hamburger-trigger-submenu">
                    <a class="hamburger__link color--white position-relative" href="#">
                      What we deliver 3.1
                    </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- SUB MENU WITHIN SUBMENU END-->
              </li>


            </ul>
            <!-- SUB MENU IN MAIN GROUP END -->


          </li>
          <!-- MAIN GROUP END -->


        </ul>

      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>

</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `e.stopPropagation();` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)) within the `$(".hamburger-trigger-submenu").click(...)` handler to prevent the event from bubbling up to `$(".hamburger--has-submenu").click(...)`.

Full Code:

```js
$(function() {

  /*
  * define vars
  */

  const header = $(".header");
  const hamburger_trigger = $(".hamburger__trigger");
  const hamburger_popup = $(".hamburger__popup");

  /*
  * open hamburger on click
  */

  $(hamburger_trigger).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(header).toggleClass("hamburger--open");
    $(hamburger_popup).toggleClass("active");
  });


  /*
  * hamburger submenu
  */

  $(".hamburger--has-submenu").click(function() {

    console.log("click");

    var child_menu = $(this).children(".hamburger__submenu");

    if ($(this).hasClass("hamburger__submenu--open")) {
      $(this).removeClass("hamburger__submenu--open");
      child_menu.removeClass("d-block");
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("hamburger__submenu--open");
      child_menu.addClass("d-block");

    }

  });


  // for children submenus

  $(".hamburger-trigger-submenu").click(function(e) {
    console.log("click");
    
    e.stopPropagation();
    
    var child_menu = $(this).children(".hamburger__submenu");

    if ($(this).hasClass("hamburger__submenu--open")) {
      child_menu.removeClass("hamburger__submenu--open");
    } else {
      child_menu.addClass("hamburger__submenu--open");
    }

  });



});
```

```css
/* HEADER */
.header {
  padding: 30px 0;
}

/* HAMBURGER */
.hamburger__trigger {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.hamburger__trigger:hover {
  color: green;
}
.hamburger__popup {
  background: black;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
  height: 0;
  padding: 40px 15px 140px 15px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.hamburger__popup.active {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.3s;
  animation: fadeIn 0.3s;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.hamburger__popup-inner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: auto;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.hamburger__li > a {
  margin: 10px 0;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
.hamburger__submenu--level-2, .hamburger__submenu--level-3, .hamburger__submenu--level-4 {
  display: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

/* GENERAL */
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.background--black {
  background: #000000;
}

.color--white {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<header class="header background--black">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-end">
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="hamburger">
          <span class="hamburger__trigger color--white">Click me</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="hamburger__popup">
    <div class="hamburger__popup-inner color--white">
      <nav class="hamburger__menu w-100">
        <ul class="hamburger__menu-ul">

          <!-- MAIN GROUP -->
          <li class="hamburger__li hamburger__depth-1 hamburger--has-submenu ">
            <a class="hamburger__parent-item color--white" href="#">
              What we deliver
            </a>

            <!-- SUB MENU IN MAIN GROUP -->
            <ul class="hamburger__submenu hamburger__submenu--level-2">

              <li class="hamburger__li hamburger__depth-2 hamburger--has-submenu hamburger-trigger-submenu">
                <a class="hamburger__link color--white hamburger__submenu-trigger" href="#">
                  <span>What we deliver 2</span>
                </a>
                <!-- SUB MENU WITHIN SUBMENU -->
                <ul class="hamburger__submenu hamburger__submenu--level-3">
                  <li class="hamburger__li hamburger__depth-3  hamburger-trigger-submenu">
                    <a class="hamburger__link color--white position-relative" href="#">
                      What we deliver 2.1
                    </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- SUB MENU WITHIN SUBMENU END-->
              </li>

              <li class="hamburger__li hamburger__depth-2 hamburger--has-submenu hamburger-trigger-submenu">
                <a class="hamburger__link color--white hamburger__submenu-trigger" href="#">
                  <span>What we deliver 3</span>
                </a>
                <!-- SUB MENU WITHIN SUBMENU -->
                <ul class="hamburger__submenu hamburger__submenu--level-3">
                  <li class="hamburger__li hamburger__depth-3  hamburger-trigger-submenu">
                    <a class="hamburger__link color--white position-relative" href="#">
                      What we deliver 3.1
                    </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- SUB MENU WITHIN SUBMENU END-->
              </li>


            </ul>
            <!-- SUB MENU IN MAIN GROUP END -->


          </li>
          <!-- MAIN GROUP END -->


        </ul>

      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>

</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

since the two functions basically do the same you could simplify them like that:

```js
$(function() {

   /*
   * define vars
   */

const header = $(".header");
const hamburger_trigger = $(".hamburger__trigger");
const hamburger_popup = $(".hamburger__popup");


/*
* open hamburger on click
*/

$(hamburger_trigger).click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(header).toggleClass("hamburger--open");
  $(hamburger_popup).toggleClass("active");
});


/*
* open menus on click
*/

$('.hamburger--has-submenu, .hamburger-trigger-submenu').on('click', function (e){
  e.stopPropagation();

  let child_menu = $(this).children('.hamburger__submenu');

  $(this).toggleClass('hamburger__submenu--open');
  child_menu.toggleClass('d-block');

})

});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can solve it with simple pseudo class in css named `:focus-within`;

`:focus-within` CSS pseudo-class matches an element if the element or any of its descendants are focused.

```css
    ul:focus-within {
      display: block;
    }
```

(no need complex js )